# Definitional Question: Can a Borel Measure be Defined on More Than the Borel Sets?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, borel-measures

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure), a Borel measure is defined as any measure that is defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a locally compact Hausdorff topological space. Obviously if you have a measure $\mu$ that is defined on a $\sigma$-algebra which strictly contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, you can restrict it to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. But would $\mu$ itself, defined on the bigger $\sigma$-algebra, still be called a Borel measure?

As a more general question: in math, when we say "defined on $X$", does that mean "defined on $X$ and nothing else" or "defined at least on $X$"?

Thank you!

Comment: I have seen both usages (sometimes one formulation is more convenient than the other) :) it gets confusing especially if consulting different sources, but I guess that's just the way things are

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, thanks!